# Limiting Number of Decimal Places in GWT?

Tags: java, math, gwt, numerical-methods

In pure Java, I would normally have a function like the one below for limiting the number of decimal places to `decimalCount` for a given number `value`. However, according to the GWT docs, "GWT does not provide full emulation for the date and number formatting classes (such as java.text.DateFormat, java.text.DecimalFormat, java.text.NumberFormat, and java.TimeFormat)." What would one do to the following function in order to make it work in GWT?

```
public static String getFormatted(double value, int decimalCount) { 
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
    decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimalCount);
    return decimalFormat.format(value);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [NumberFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html) (com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat) in the GWT Javadoc.

I've never used it but I see this example in there:

```
// Custom format
value = 12345.6789;
formatted = NumberFormat.getFormat("000000.000000").format(value);
// prints 012345.678900 in the default locale
GWT.log("Formatted string is" + formatted);
```

So this should work for you.

### **Update**

This method provides the same functionality as the one in your question. I went ahead and asked for the most efficient way to go about this, see that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226623/most-efficient-way-to-fill-a-string-with-a-specified-length-with-a-specified-char/7226643#7226643). (Sorry this answer has been edited so much - it was just bugging me)

```
public static String getFormatted(double value, int decimalCount) {
    StringBuilder numberPattern = new StringBuilder(
            (decimalCount <= 0) ? "" : ".");
    for (int i = 0; i < decimalCount; i++) {
        numberPattern.append('0');
    }
    return NumberFormat.getFormat(numberPattern.toString()).format(value);
}
```

Alternatives include using a set amount of "0"'s and using substring to pull out the required pattern as @Thomas Broyer mentioned in the comments.

Comment: You'd better do a `"0000000000".substring(0, decimalCount)` (assuming `decimalCount` is between 1 and 10) than concatenations, performance-wise.

Comment: IMO, the best approach is to combine the StringBuilder with a substring (if you need 24 "0"'s, then first append a 10-char-long string to the StringBuilder before appending a `substring(0, 4)`; or alternatively, append the 10-char-long string three times, and take a `substring(0, 24)` of the computed whole string). And if you need to do it very often in your app, try different variations and benchmark them!

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
NumberFormat decimalFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat(".##");
```

from GWT library which will render for example 1234.789789 to 1234.78

You can find a full working example here: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwNumberFormat

Comment: Just a hint: with .## you'll get 1234.79 and not 1234.78 :). NumberFormat rounds where necessary.

Comment: and do you know how troncate instead of rounding up?

Answer (score 1):

In current GWT (2.5, 2.6), there is now:

```
private final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat();

System.out.println(numberFormat.format(myFloat));
```

Edit: added GWT versions per request

Comment: Please state what version is the "current GWT" so there won't be any confusions

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the decimal format within the UiBinder file

```html
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="grid">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <g:Label>
            <ui:msg description="total">Total:</ui:msg>
        </g:Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <g:NumberLabel customFormat="0.00" ui:field="total"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```